The case for accepting ANY valid ATA in your instruction, no matter what its authority is
Sometimes, your program doesn't care about the authority of the input ATA, as long as the ATA has the correct/valid Mint.
One such case is when you simply want to transfer some tokens to a recipient's ATA (from a sender's ATA). As long as both of the ATAs have been derived from the same Mint account, you don't care who controls the ATA - and can just transfer the tokens to it.
Still, if you try to only specify the associated_token::mint of an InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount> ATA in the #[derive(Accounts)] struct of your instruction, the compiler won't be satisfied until you also specify the authority.
Declaring the ATA as a simple #[account(mut)] and validating its Mint field inside the instruction's logic is not fun either.
Having all of the above in mind, I have 2 questions:

Is it possible to only specify the Mint of an InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>?
If not, then, what is the recommended approach for this situation?

For more details, check out this sample code on the Solana Playground. Note that it doesn't build until you uncomment the lines that:

define the authority's account (line 55) and
constrain the ATA's authority, referencing the above account (line 60)

P.S. Is it that without also specifying the ATA's authority, it simply can't be checked (technically) that the ATA has been derived from a certain/expected Mint?

I think in your use case it would suffice to use
    #[account(mut)]
    pub some_ata: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,

because when you invoke TransferChecked it will validate the mints between the two accounts match anyways. In token22 invoke_transfer_checked also validates the mint.
If you just want to perform this validation so you can emit a custom error before you could do something like
    #[account(mut,
        constraint = some_ata.mint == mint.key() @ SomeError
    )]

or similar in your handler. This would also allow you to use Transfer instead of TransferChecked which is marginally less CU usage.
More generally, if the ix is sending funds to some user defined destination with no limitations, it's on them to put a valid ATA as the destination.
